# find core file code where import data reading from csv file

Tags: magento-1.9, import, products

Hello developers,

I need little help,Magento is providing import/export data for products,customers using csv files.

When I go `System > Import/Export > Import` ,select `products` for `Entity types` and import product `*.csv` file and it successfully imported.But my question is where is code in core files where read and write data one by one from csv file for products.

I tried to find in `app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/controllers/Adminhtml/ImportController.php` and in this `ImportController.php` file I show `startAction()` method I also show `importSource()` method in `Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import.php` file I can not find fetch data from csv file.I effort but I could not success to find code in core files.Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see it's in the import.php file you where stated earlier.

> /**
>        * Import source file structure to DB.
>        *
>        * @return void
>        */

The code under these comment is the beginning of checking the file, validating and a few more rows down it's about uploading the checked file.

Good luck.

Comment: Finally I found code _saveProducts(),_saveStockItem() used they are call in   _importData() function and it is used to save product data.see line number 476. method in Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php

Comment: You where looking to fetch not save data as you statement is looking for. At least you found what you needed.

Comment: I already mentioned in question that read and write data from CSV..thanks for help

Comment: Fair enough..best of luck on the project..